# Does moving a list from a navigation folder to another navigation folder cause any impact

Tags: list, navigation

Suppose I have a List called `Jan 2011 Reports` inside the `Lists` Heading, I moved to another Heading, say `2011 Reports` (which I created to keep all the Jan to Dec 2011 reports), will it affect the operations of the `Jan 2011 Reports` list (e.g. coding that modify item in this list)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All it will do is organize the Quick Launch icons how you would like. The list itself is still in the same place as before, it is just now organized on the quick launch under a new header.

If you were to move it from the "Current Navigation" heading up to the "Global Navigation" it would add it to your top link bar.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not affect the list.